# PHP Передача спецсимволов методом GET и POST

Tags: php, post, get

Есть скрипт, который принимает определенный набор символов из формы.
Все работает корректно, пока среди символов не появляются "+", "&", "\", "/"
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно передать подобные данные?
Заран

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать функции [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) и [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php)

Первая заменяет спецсимволы на корректное URL-представление, а вторая, соответственно, наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы формируете строку для метода GET на стороне клиента (в браузере), потом отправляете, то используйте при формировании запроса в javascript функцию [encodeURIComponent](http://javascript.ru/encodeuricomponent) .

Если строка для метода GET формируется на стороне сервера, то используйте функцию **urlencode** для преобразования строки (и **urldecode** для расшифровки потом).

А вообще, для передачи данных лучше использовать метод POST.